# React-DatePicker giving default values on wrong format

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using `react-datepicker`. My date picker format is `MM/DD/YYYY` but when I am writing `DD/MM/YYYY` (`31/12/2020`) and typing 3 in date picker it's moving to march month in the date picker and after completing full date and coming out of date picker its moving `03/01/2020` but it should give invalid date message.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new that recreate the issue?